# Update Data Users in PDO Not Work

Tags: php, pdo

Previously I was using Old MySQL to update, but now I try to change the total to PDO on the recommendation of friends.

However I am constrained when setting up the form to update information about users.

I use this code:

```
public function runQuery($sql)
{
    $aboutMe = $this->conn->prepare($sql);

    return $aboutMe;
}

class Database
{   
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "...";
    private $username = "...";
    private $password = "...";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}


    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
    $utentang = strip_tags($_POST['txt_tentang']);

        try
        {
            $aboutMe = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE users SET tentang=:ttg where id=:id");
            $aboutMe->execute(array(':ttg'=>$utentang, ':id'=>$id));
            $aboutMe->bindValue(':ttg', $utentang);
            $tentangSaya=$aboutMe->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
};
```

HTML

```
<form method="post">
<div class="center">
<h2>Your About</h2> 

<p><textarea name="txt_tentang" id="tentang"></textarea></p>
<input id="button" type="submit" value="Simpan" name="update"/>
</div>
</form>
```

The above code does not run.
What is wrong?
PHP Version 5.5

Comment: `$aboutMe->execute(array('ttg'=>$utentang, 'id'=>$id));`, no need to bindvalue after

Comment: the code seems to be a little mixed up ( to me ) - the `runQuery` method belongs to the `$auth_user` but `$this->conn` belongs to `Database`???

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong?

Frankly - nearly everything. From the class structure to the idea of fetching result of the *update* query.

It seems you are using some highly unreliable tutorial to learn PDO. Let me offer one I wrote, [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo), from which you will easy learn the proper way.

Here is your update code fixed:

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
    $utentang = strip_tags($_POST['txt_tentang']);
    $stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("UPDATE users SET tentang=:ttg where id=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':ttg'=>$utentang, ':id'=>$id));
}
```

Note that you should neither bind, fetch or catch here.